# How to do "GET" request for Confluence page content with REST API

Tags: c#, azure-functions, httprequest, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am a beginner in C# and also working with REST API for the first time. 
I want to use an Azure Function with a HTTP trigger to get the content from a Confluence page via REST API "GET". 
I have specified `ConfluenceUser`, `ConfluenceAPI` and `ConfluenceDomain` in the `local.settings.json` file.

**Code (Visual Studio 2019):**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpClientEx
{
    class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var confBuild = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            //Basic Authentication
            var user = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(confBuild["ConfluenceUser"]);
            var api = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(confBuild["ConfluenceAPI"]);
            var domain = confBuild["ConfluenceDomain"];

            string basic_auth = Convert.ToBase64String(user) + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(api);

            string pageid = "1234567";
            string page = "https://" + domain + "/wiki/rest/api/content/" + pageid;

        }
        private static async Task<string> getPageContent(string domain, int pageid, string basic_auth)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basic_auth);

                var response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format("https://" + domain + "/wiki/rest/api/content/" + pageid.ToString() + "?expand=space,metadata.labels"));
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My questions:** 
Did I do the GET request correctly? 
How can I see the content I got from the Confluence page?

Comment: I've removed your `[visual-studio]` tag because it's reserved for questions about Visual Studio.

Comment: @John Alright, thank you!

Comment: I would think that your current code would return the result if the request was successful. I would add `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` between the `var response = ` and `var result = `lines so that an exception will be thrown if the status code from the server you're accessing shows the call to be unsuccessful.

Comment: what errormessage do you get? you are not calling your `getPageContent` method?

Comment: @Pio I'm assuming that `getPageContent` is called by Azure's Functions framework.

Comment: As an aside: It seems like the basic_auth parameters are secret, but allowing the user to directly specify the "domain" (which could actually be their own page) would allow them to intercept the Authorization header. I'm not sure if this is in any way a security concern for you, but I thought it best to point it out anyway.

Comment: @John Thank you for the help! I've added `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` and it seems to work. Do you perhaps now how I could see the content I got from the page? Is there a way to do so in Visual Studio? Because I can't find anything in the Output field

Comment: To be honest, it might be best to try and make the request on your local machine to diagnose what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a rest API in Azure function, please refer to the following steps

1. Install [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools)
2. Create Azure function

```
#create project
func init LocalFunctionProj --dotnet
cd LocalFunctionProj
#create httptrigger function
func new --name Http --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel "anonymous"
```

3. Update project

a. add the following settings to `local.settings.json`

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "ConfluenceUser":"",
        "ConfluenceAPI":"",
        "ConfluenceDomain":""
    }
}
```

b. Update code in `Http.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace LocalFunctionProj
{
    
    public static class Http
    {
        private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        [FunctionName("Http")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var confBuild = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            //Basic Authentication
            var user =confBuild["ConfluenceUser"];
            var api = confBuild["ConfluenceAPI"];
            var domain = confBuild["ConfluenceDomain"];
              httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", user, api))));
            object  body = null;
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(
                        $"https://{domain}/wiki/rest/api/content/163979"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               
                body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(body);
        }
    }
}
```

4. Test

Use the following command to run the project

```
func start
```

[image]